# Problems with staggered image and input field

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, input-field

I have problems with the placement of the image and the input field. They are placed in a staggered way. I want them to be placed right next to each other, on a straight horizontal line. You can see the problem on the image below.

[image]

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/58/)

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

            <!--Inbox list and button to add a card-->
            <div id="inboxList" class="cellContainer">
                <p style="display: inline">Inbox</p> 
                <!--Button to add a Card-->
                <input type="button" id="AddCardBtn" value="+ Add a Card..."/> 
                <hr class="fancy-line"/> <br/>

                <!--Card div-->
                <div id="userAddedCard"> <br/>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div'); 
    $('<img />', { "src": "/Pages/Images/calendar.png" }).addClass('image').appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text", "class": "ctb" }).addClass('ctb').appendTo($div);
```

CSS:

```
.ctb {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;    
    padding-left:2%;
}

.image {
    display:inline-block;
    height:19px;
    width:19px;
    padding-top:7%;
    padding-left:5%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add for class **CSS**

```
.ctb
{
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 2%;
margin: 0px;
}
.image
{
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add  vertical-align: bottom to your .image element that should line everything up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated Fiddle,

[DEMO Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/85/)

```
<!--Card div-->
        <div id="userAddedCard"> <br/>

        </div>
  .image {
   display:inline-block;
   height:19px;
   width:19px;
   /*padding-top:7%;
   padding-left:5%;
   padding-right:2%;*/
   vertical-align:top;

}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to apply `display: block;` to both text and image instead of `display:inline-block;`

```
.ctb {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;    
    padding-left:2%;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    height:19px;
    width:19px;
    padding-top:7%;
    padding-left:5%;

}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/89/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/62QY8/88/). Updated following classes

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:19px;
    width:19px;
    padding-left:5%;
     margin-top: 0.4%;
}


#inboxList {
    width: 275px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-top: 0.4%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #828282;
    overflow: auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```